# Definition of length of a sequence

Tags: set-theory, definition, descriptive-set-theory

In [definition $3.11$](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5724v2.pdf), the author defined the following rank:

> If the sets $A$ and $B$ can be separated by a transfinite difference
>   of closed sets, then let $\alpha_1(A,B)$ denote the ***length of the
>   shortest such sequence***, otherwise let $\alpha_1(A,B)=\omega_1$.

Question: What is the definition of 'length of a sequence'? Does it mean the index $\theta$ where the sequence starts to stabilize, i.e. $F_\theta = F_{\theta+1}$

Remark: Let $(F_\eta)_{\eta < \lambda}$ be a decreasing sequence of sets. Assume that $F_0 = X$ (Polish space) and $F_\eta=\bigcap_{\theta<\eta}F_\theta$ for every limit $\eta$ and if $\lambda$ is a limit, then $\bigcap_{\eta<\lambda}F_\eta=\emptyset$. A set $H$ is the ***transfinite difference*** of $(F_\eta)_{\eta < \lambda}$ if $H = \bigcup_{\eta<\lambda, even \eta} {(F_\eta \backslash F_{\eta+1}})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the sequence $(F_\eta)_{\eta < \lambda}$ is just $\lambda$.

Maybe it's nitpicky, but I'd prefer to call this a "$\lambda$-sequence" and reserve the word "sequence" for the case where $\lambda = \omega$ (the set of natural numbers).

Comment: The preferred language obviously should depend on the context, but in set theory most of our sequences have length $> \omega$ and commonly we don't want to specify the length. Hence just referring to them as sequences has become the norm. (Also, what a sequence is - as a set - can differ a bit from author to author, but that's a different story and most of the time inconsequential.)